# std::vector operations slower on certain systems

Tags: c++

As a personal project, I am developing a simple 2D game engine with realtime collision physics in C++. My collisions are handled by calculating the time to collision between unique pairs of objects. For this, I constructed my own contiguous 2D matrix class using an `std::vector<float>` to store these collision times.

A part of my main physics loop involves adding a constant value to all the elements in the collision matrix, called `Matrix2D::addConstValue(float)`. For some reason, certain systems report this function as using a large proportion of CPU time in gprof. As a result, the program runs far slower in general than on others. For example, on one system a large number of collisions at once results in a small framerate dip. On the worse systems, this exact same set of collisions can bring the framerate into single digits and slow down the simulation significantly.

These are the systems I have run the program on:

```
PC 1:

OS: Windows7
CPU: AMD Phenom II x4 960T
GPU: AMD Radeon HD6850
RAM: 8GB
Program performance: Good

PC2:

OS: Windows 10
CPU: Intel i5 2500K
GPU: AMD Radeon HD7970
RAM: 8GB
Program Performance: Bad

PC3 (laptop):

OS: Windows 10 + Xubuntu 16.04 (Dual boot)
CPU: Intel i5 5600u
GPU: Intel HD5000
RAM: 12GB
Program Performance: Good in Xubuntu, bad in Windows 10

PC4:

OS: Windows 10
CPU: AMD FX-6300
GPU: nVidia GTX 970
RAM: 8GB
Program Performance: Good
```

I would have expected PC2 to outperform PC1, but PC2 reports far higher CPU usage as a result of calls to the above matrix function. Below are the gprof results for PC1 and PC2

PC1:

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls   s/call   s/call  name    
 14.44      0.66     0.66 81222460     0.00     0.00  Ball::getDistance(Ball&)
 12.47      1.23     0.57 319194829     0.00     0.00  sfVectorMath::dot(sf::Vector2<float>, sf::Vector2<float>)
 12.47      1.80     0.57 55453088     0.00     0.00  Collisions::timeToCollision(Ball&, Ball&)
 11.16      2.31     0.51 81222460     0.00     0.00  Ball::getGPE(Ball&)
  6.78      2.62     0.31 153865899     0.00     0.00  Matrix2d::getElementValue(int, int)
```

PC2:

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls   s/call   s/call  name    
 77.83     23.49    23.49     8332     0.00     0.00  Matrix2d::addConstValue(float)
  7.59     25.78     2.29                             _mcount_private
  4.67     27.19     1.41 40603954     0.00     0.00  Collisions::timeToCollision(Ball&, Ball&)
  1.29     27.58     0.39                             pow
  1.19     27.94     0.36    11466     0.00     0.00  Matrix2d::getMatrixMin()
  0.99     28.24     0.30 206105049     0.00     0.00  sfVectorMath::dot(sf::Vector2<float>, sf::Vector2<float>)
  0.93     28.52     0.28                             internal_modf
  0.83     28.77     0.25 122492898     0.00     0.00  Matrix2d::getElementValue(int, int)
```

I am really at a loss as to what's going on. Some other details: Both the linux and windows versions were compiled with GCC 6.1.0 and SFML 2.4.2. Natively compiling on Windows 10 made no change to the performance.

Edit: Also, the implementation of `addConstValue`

```
void Matrix2d::addConstValue(float value)
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<matrix.size(); ++i)
        matrix.at(i) += value;
}
```

Comment: "Good" and "bad" are not exactly useful performance metrics

Comment: You don't say what compiler options you used.

Comment: See my edit: "For example, on one system a large number of collisions at once results in a small framerate dip. On the worse systems, this exact same set of collisions can bring the framerate into single digits and slow down the simulation significantly."

Comment: I used: `i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -std=c++14 -fexceptions -O2 -std=c++14 -pg -DSFML_STATIC -std=c++14 -I`

Comment: I saw that but that is still not a set of numbers to compare. Be methodical. Be mathematical.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: Do not store NaNs in a vector and certainly don't attempt to read them! Also try and avoid operating on NaNs just in case.**

I tested the performance of my matrix class by setting up a 242*242 matrix and filling with either zeros or `std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN()`. I then executed the `addConstValue(float)` function on the matrix. Below is a table of average time taken per call. 50000 calls were done when the matrix was filled with zeros, 500 when filled with NaNs:

```
W10 2500k, filled with zeros: 34.54µs
W10 2500k, filled with NaNs: 6121.64µs
W7 960T, filled with zeros: 52.73µs
W7 960T, filled with NaNs: 62.4µs
W10 i5 5600u, filled with zeros: 27.50µs
W10 i5 5600u, filled with NaNs: 7062.63µs
```

So, it's clear that attempting to operate on NaNs is at ~200 times slower on PCs 2 and 3. Strangely, this bottleneck does not exist on the AMD machine. I then added a quick check to see if a vector element is a nan (using `std::isnan()`) inside `addConstValue(float)`. Below are the per call execution times:

```
W10 2500k, filled with zeros: 70.05µs
W10 2500k, filled with NaNs: 70.05µs
W10 i5 5600u, filled with zeros: 93.75µs
W10 i5 5600u, filled with NaNs: 62.50µs
```

This causes the execution time to double for matrices filled with zeros, but reduces the time significantly for those filled with NaNs.

Reducing the problem even further, I set up a loop to add a constant float to a bare NaN, and another adding to a `std::vector` containing only one NaN over 10 million cycles. Here's the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
    float nan = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
    std::vector<float> nanvec = {nan};

    int noPasses = 10000000;

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    for(int i=0; i<noPasses; ++i)
        nan += -1.0f;

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    cout << "Bare float NaN: " << duration << " microseconds\n" ;


    t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    for(int i=0; i<noPasses; ++i)
        nanvec[0] += -1.0f;

    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = duration_cast<microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    cout << "Vector NaN: " << duration << " microseconds\n" ;

    return 0;
}
```

My output (W10, i5 2500k):

```
Bare float NaN: 0 microseconds
Vector NaN: 1122833 microseconds
```

So it looks like the CPU knows to ignore NaN operations. Is it possible that retrieving a NaN from a container results in these long execution times? I also still don't know why this problem would occur only on some systems.

In any case, I incorporated the quick fix of checking for NaNs into my game engine and the speedup is incredible. There are no longer any bottlenecks related to pulling NaNs from a vector (checked with gprof). I may try and find a way to avoid having to check just to gain that extra 50% performance per call.

Comment: I would say that the compiler know you have a `NAN` and is able to optimize away the first loop but not the second one. The use of a vector would require deeper analysis and a compiler make some trade off between increased compilation time and potential performance gain.

Comment: It is not really clear what is happening with your code, as we don't have anything to play with. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I agree with @Phil1970 that in this example the first `NaN` loop probably gets thrown away by the compiler. In general however, you have to be aware that the performance of `NaN` and `vector` is implementation dependent. Thus OS, processor model, ... matter. My guess at your simulation performance would be, that the systems you describe as *good* have a cache model better suited to your operations.